# Location of file when we run in test

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 2.6 and intellij.

I want to test a class who create a pdf from a html file generated with thymeleaf.

Structure of the project

[image]

In the test repository, I have my class and i created a resources folder where my json.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestamentApplication.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PdfGeneratorTest {

    @Autowired
    PdfGenerator generator;

    public void generatePdf(){
        try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Testament testament = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("testament1.json").toFile(), Testament.class);

        generator.createPdf("testament/testament", "html", testament, "testament");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

For the test, spring boot will use directly the resources folder located in test?

Samething for the application-test.properties or I need to copy in the resources folder of the test?

Comment: Start the path with a `/`, and you'll be fine.

Comment: need to put: mapper.readValue(Paths.get("src/test/resources/testament1.json").toFile() to be able to read the file

Comment: You don’t. Use `Class.getResources(“/myfile”)`